# How to scrape data from javascript code from HTML page by using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am working to **scrape** the actual data of graph from the site. But this data in javascript code and store in the list. Then please tell me the how to **scrape** this data by using python.

[click here and see the HTML page image.

In this image show script tag and in this tag one column[] list.In this list data is store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ne6U.jpg)

Then please send the solution of this problem.

This is my python code

---

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
urlpage = 'http://www.stockgraph.com/'  //This is not original url ,above give
the link of  image of html page.

page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
script=soup.find('script',attrs={'class':'col-md-9 col-md-push-3'})
print(script)

---

In the above code open url and find out the script tag but I can't **scrape** javascript code.
please tell me the solution.
My data in script tag and store in the list then how to **scrape** this data

Comment: Did you make any attempts to solve that problem yourself already?

Comment: It seems like you expect us to just do everything for you. Please share some code as to what you have done so far, and where you are stuck at.

Comment: sir see the HTML page image .                                                                                                    In this image give the script tag -----> in this tag javascript code ---->my actual data in                            column: [15040700000,150907389900,......   ]                                                     I want this column content data.

Comment: FYI It’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

To get you off in the right direction, I will try to guide you in what you need to do.

First you need to use something to read your webpage like urllib

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
page_source = response.read()
```

You will then need to parse this code using another Module like BeautifulSoup

Follow some documents to get you started on scraping your website 
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe/